# C3 js grouped bar chart scolling and fixing y axis issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, c3.js

Here is my output image:

[image]

I have a grouped bar chart in C3. I have scroll with x-axis with respect to data. While scrolling x-axis my y axis moves along with. How to fix position of y-axis fixed on screen?
Since I have to represent large number of data so I want scroll on x-axis and Y-axis need to be fixed and bar width need to same as previous because as number of data increases bar width gets automatically decreases.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  var months = ['Jan 2016', 'Feb2016', 'Feb2016', 'Jan 2016', 'Feb2016', 'Feb2016'];
  var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
      bindto: '#chart',
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 30, 200, 100],
        ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 30, 200, 100]
      ],
      type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
      width: {
        ratio: 0.6
      }
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: months,
        label: {
          text: 'open cases',
          position: 'outer-middle'
        }
      },
      y: {
        label: {
          text: 'open cases',
          position: 'outer-middle'
        }
      }


    },

  });
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.3/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.5.0/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.3/c3.js"></script>


<body>
  <div style="width:300px;overflow-x:auto">
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use c3's zoom behaviour? Here, use the mouse wheel over the chart to zoom in / out, and use left-click and drag to move the chart

Only other change, is moving the svg width declaration from css into the c3 chart declaration

```js
$(function() {
  var months = ['Jan 2016', 'Feb2016', 'Feb2016', 'Jan 2016', 'Feb2016', 'Feb2016'];
  var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
      bindto: '#chart',
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 30, 200, 100],
        ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 30, 200, 100]
      ],
      type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
      width: {
        ratio: 0.6
      }
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: months,
        label: {
          text: 'open cases',
          position: 'outer-middle'
        }
      },
      y: {
        label: {
          text: 'open cases',
          position: 'outer-middle'
        }
      }


    },
zoom: {
    enabled: true
},
size: {
   width: 260,
},
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.3/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.5.0/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.3/c3.js"></script>


<body>
  <div style="width:300px">
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry but i want scrolling and width need to be fixed because I need x-axis labels

Comment: It does do scrolling and the width of the svg is fixed. The width of the bars can be anything you want, just zoom in/out till you're happy.

Comment: Sorry but I want the same fuctionality as stated above Because for this If data gets increase the x-axis labels gets overlapped